# Zend Form - View helper and form decorator

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-view, zend-decorators

What is the difference between a zend form decorator and a view helper? I want to use some awesome Jquery plugins for my form but finding hard to understand about decorators and view helpers, for example the [following](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html) is the Twitter bootstrap CSS framework's javascript plugins

[This](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) is a multiple option autocomplete.

How to use these elements in my form?, if I want to create a re-usable code, these will be  decorators or helpers?

I am new to Zend, in real time zend projects, custom HTML forms are used or Zend_Form.The forms were already created by a designer and given to me.

Comment: What markup would be required for what you want to use, and what markup are you currently getting?

Comment: It will be a <input> text.and some jquery code..As per what I read, I think i need to create custom jquery plugins as a view helper to print the html & jquery code. then create a custom form element and call the view helper in that, right?? but i donno how my jquery code will show up head section if do this, coz i referred ZendX library, this is how they do i think..

Answer (score -1):

I would look at the existing ZF Partial View Helper and see if that meets your needs as is.  You can then inject any third-party resources you need through other helpers.

Below is the relevant ZF docs.  These are for 1.12, but if I recall my reading, this is fundamentally the same in 2.x.

[Partial Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial)

[HeadScript](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headscript)